# For (not foreach) loop in Python

Tags: python

I need to make a simple python script, but as I mostly do PHP / C++ I find it hard to manage myself without simple for loops.
Let's say I have a code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < some_string_length; i++)
{
//do something...
}
```

As you can see it simply goes as many times as many letters I have in my string. Of course, I could do this in a while loop, but that has an issue. I have to either create a variable outside of the loop which will make it global or create it inside the loop, but this variable's value can't be used in the argument of loop.

Wrong:

```
while(i < some_string_length)
{
i = something; //declaring i for the first time
i++;
}
```

As you can see it doesn't make sense at all. So how can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you show the actual data you need to iterate over and how you want to use it?

Comment: You can try build your own C-style for loop in Python, but I really can't see why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The construct from other languages

```
for (int i = start; i < stop; i += step) { … }
```

translates directly into a Python for loop over a [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    …
```

By default, `step` is 1, so you don’t need to specify it for `i++`. `start` defaults to zero, so you can also leave that out, if you start with `i = 0`:

```
for i in range(stop): # the same as `for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++)`
    …
```

So, if you want to iterate `i` over the length of a string, you can just do this:

```
for i in range(len(my_string)):
    …
```

Usually, you would want to access the character of that string though, so you can just iterate over the characters directly:

```
for char in my_string:
    …
```

Or, if you really do need the index as well, you can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get both:

```
for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
    …
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for i, item in enumerate(some_string):
    # i is the index, item is the actual element
```

I think you'd be surprised how rarely you actually need `i`, though. You're better off learning how to use Python idioms, rather than forcing yourself to write PHP/C++ code in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i in range(0,some_string_length):
    # do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `range` function

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "x: %d" (x)
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `string s`:

```
s = "some string"
```

you can do this:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print i
```